# How to split @vue/cli 3 "pages" vendor file

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

i follow this topic [Build the app in multi-page mode](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) in Vue Cli doc, it working fine but i realize that there is only 1 vendor file instead of 2 (per page entry).

How can i split vendor file? i don't want to have one unnecessary big vendor file shared across many page entries. (i want to have it in single app).

[image]

[image]

For screenshot above, i want to have one vendor file for index.xxx.js and one for report.xxx.js

Please suggest, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/monitor/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      chunks: ['chunk-common', 'chunk-index-vendors', 'index']
    },
    report: {
      entry: 'src/report/main.js',
      chunks: ['chunk-common', 'chunk-report-vendors', 'report']
    }
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    const options = module.exports
    const pages = options.pages
    const pageKeys = Object.keys(pages)

    // Long-term caching

    const IS_VENDOR = /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/

    config.optimization
      .splitChunks({
        cacheGroups: {
          ...pageKeys.map(key => ({
            name: `chunk-${key}-vendors`,
            priority: -11,
            chunks: chunk => chunk.name === key,
            test: IS_VENDOR,
            enforce: true,
          })),
          common: {
            name: 'chunk-common',
            priority: -20,
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 2,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            enforce: true,
          },
        },
      })
  }
}
```

It's based on the GitHub thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2381#issuecomment-425038367